# Personal Line of Credit and Credit Utilization rate

Tags: credit-score, credit, line-of-credit

Let's say I have a Personal Line of Credit for 20,000. If I use 80% of it, will it have the same effect (on Credit Scores) as that of a Credit Card with 80% utilization?

Answer (score 2):

I know that when I use my HELOC, there's no impact to utilization. A line of credit distinct from a credit card, should not impact either, 
I'd look at a site such as CreditKarma to see what your utilization looks like, and how the line of credit is treated.

Comment: I haven't opened the Line-Of-Credit account yet. I wanted to find out the effect on utilization-rate before I open one up. Thanks for your input though. I will wait if anyone with an open line-of-credit can answer!